# How to append one file to the other, with first file being edited, hence can't use usual cat command

Tags: unix, awk, command, pipe, cat

Suppose that I have two files, each of them have header in the first line and records in the remaining lines. And I want to concatenate two files into one, but don't include header twice.

I tried the following commands while googling for the answer, (hence I may not cope in an optimal way).

```
cat awk 'NR!=1 {printf "%s\n", $1}' file2.csv >| file.csv
```

However, I got the following error.

```
cat: awk: No such file or directory
cat: NR!=1 {printf "%s\n",$1}: No such file or directory
```

It looks like `cat` recognized `awk` as files, not commands. I want the result of `awk` to be the content of files, so I also tried to pipe it to the argument of `cat`.

```
awk 'NR!=1 {printf "%s\n", $1}' file2.csv > cat file.csv
```

However, in this way, I got file `cat`, in which I got the result of `awk`...

So how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some grouping:

```
{ 
    cat file1
    sed '1d' file2
} > file.csv
```

As one line

```
{ cat file1; sed '1d' file2; } > file.csv
```

The semicolon before the ending brace is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
{cat file1; tail -n +2 file2} > out
```

Answer (score 0):

Print first line from first file, then print line #2 to the end of any file

```
awk 'NR==1||FNR>1' file1 file2 (file3 file4 ..) > outfile
```